# Event driven architecture/programming

Tags: architecture

Is Event driven architecture an architectural style or a cross-cutting concern?  Probably any architectural choice could be labeled as a cross-cutting concern, because it has tendrils in every aspect of the software.  Does EDA/EDP fall under a cross-cutting concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a family of styles that allow components to communicate through asynchronous messages. Systems based on event-based styles are often organized as a loosely coupled federation of components that trigger behavior in other components through events.

A variety of event styles exist, for example:

- Point-to-Point
- Publish-Subscribe

Crosscutting concerns are addressed by aspect style.

Aspect style is a module style, event-based style - runtime style, so it's important not to mix them up.

Comment: Hmmm, it is true crosscutting concerns are related to aspect style.  However, EVP solves or minimizes the impact of some cross-cutting concerns.  That is where I'm starting to mix the two in my brain

Answer (score 1):

A concern is usually a behaviour in a computer program. A cross-cutting concern would be a behaviour that interacts with many other parts of the system. An event-driven architecture is a design pattern rather than a behaviour in a program so I would argue that it is not a cross-cutting concern.

Comment: I would also add that at, say, the scale of a Mediator or EventAggregator -- this is not cross-cutting but rather good SIP.

Answer (score 0):

not a cross cutting concern.  Architectures give solutions for implementing cross cutting concerns.  I disagree with the notion that 'any architectural choice could be labeled a cross-cutting concern'.

Think about it this way, regardless of whether you go with an event-driven model, you still have to address your cross cutting concerns like security, metrics, etc.  The two concepts are orthogonal.